# How can i compare the values of excel cell values while using SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I am importing Excelsheet into sql server database i need to check certain things before importing the sheet, such as  i have a column called passport which must have values starting with alphabet only and must have rest of the characters as numbers (only).

```
   DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
            dt7.Load(dr);
            DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow[dt7.Rows.Count];
            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelTable";
                dt7.Rows.CopyTo(ExcelRows, 0);

                for (int i = 0; i < ExcelRows.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ExcelRows[i]["data"] == DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        // Include any actions to perform if there is no date
                        //ExcelRows[i]["data"] = Convert.ToString(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DateTime oldDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ExcelRows[i]["data"]).Date;
                        DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate).Date;
                        ExcelRows[i]["data"] = newDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    }



                }
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ExcelRows);
```

Comment: where is the passport column in above code?

Comment: So you need to check it before BCP? Is it ok to do it in DB using query/SP? Because it should be relatively simple using SQL Servers built-in functions.

Comment: @Anandkumar its not i am going to add passport i, i have just posted this code to show what approach i am using to upload excel

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić it would be much better if i can do it using c#code itself

Comment: @Arbaaz: ok, I'll stop then here, I'm too slow in ADO.NET so someone will answer much faster. I'll just recommend using the same connection for querying and BCP, sou you don't get performance penalty; like this: `using (SqlConnection sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. What you can do is to Perform your validation before Bulk operation.

Comment: THat's exactly what i want to do but question is how?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is `'NO'`. You can not validate while performing SqlBulk operation. What you can do is to validate the `Datatable` before performing the SqlBulk operation.

```
private bool Validate(Datatable dt)
{
     //Perform your validation
     // return true/false 
}

        DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
        dt7.Load(dr);
        DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow[dt7.Rows.Count];
        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server

        // Perform your validation here. If not validated then skip with some message.
        if(!Validate(dt7))
        {
             //Show Message
             return;
        }            

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelTable";
            dt7.Rows.CopyTo(ExcelRows, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < ExcelRows.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ExcelRows[i]["data"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    // Include any actions to perform if there is no date
                    //ExcelRows[i]["data"] = Convert.ToString(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime oldDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ExcelRows[i]["data"]).Date;
                    DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate).Date;
                    ExcelRows[i]["data"] = newDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                }



            }
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ExcelRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform validation of excel cell values while uploading the excel sheet.
Two ways:

1. Bring the Excel data in a datatable and run through it doing validations and recording discrepancies. After you have finished the validations show the errors to the user or if there are no more erors do a sqlbulkcopy. All this is done at the c# level.
2. On the sql front, bring the Excel data in a datatable do sqlbulkcopy straight a way in a temp table in your database. Then call a stored proc which will validate the bulk uploaded data and send out the errors. If there are errors alert the user, else do a bulk copy or call a stored proc to pull the data from your temp table to your real table.

You choose.